# How to fix data frame indexing issue in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv dataset with n rows, and the top row is filled with numbers instead of labels. However, when I print out the values of the dataframe, it indexes row "0" as the second row, completely ignoring the top row. I assume this may have to do with the fact that Pandas treats the dataframe's first row and columns as labels. So, how can I get around this so that it incorporates the first row without shifting all of my values in the csv file? Thank you.

Comment: `pd.read_csv(..., header=None)`?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny yes, thank you!